# How to handle UI Thread Updating C# Xamarin.Froms

Tags: c#, xamarin

I have developed and application that updates my UI at two different times, let me explain. There is a grid of buttons that update every 2 seconds using an `OnTimedEvent` and the `Timer` class. However, I have a score that can update anytime the user clicks. My dilemma comes in the form of the entire UI updates when the grid updates. I know why this happens, or at least I beleive I do, though, I don't know how to solve this. Feedback, Input, solutions welcome. Completely new to any UI threading. I have to allow the 2 seconds to the user to make a selection before continuing, however the user can run up the count multiple times in those 2 seconds, but it won't update the count until the threat count of 2 seconds is over. I have exhausted all my ideas! Thanks in advance.

```html
 private void SetTimer()
 {
   // Create a timer with a two second interval.
   aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(2000);
   // Hook up the Elapsed event for the timer. 
   aTimer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
   aTimer.AutoReset = true;
   aTimer.Enabled = true;
}
private void OnTimedEvent(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
   Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
   {
   /*
   ...
   */
               
   for (int i = 0; i < gridSizeToInt; i++)
   {
        NewGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });
        NewGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });
        for (int j = 1; j <= gridSizeToInt; j++)
        {
            //rand num generator code
           Button newBtn;
           NewGrid.Children.Add(newBtn = new Button{BackgroundColor = ColorArray[temp1]}, i, j);
           newBtn.Clicked += Button_Click;
           clickCountLabel.Text = "Click Count: " + ClickCount;
        }
    }
   
  });
}
```

Comment: "I know why this happens" - it would be helpful if you shared your theory with us

Comment: I'm doing all my management under the `InvokeMainThread` is the reason.. I think

Comment: Do you have an event handler to update the UI when a button is clicked?
If you are only updating the UI when the timer expires, your scenario makes sense.
It's difficult to tell what is happening without additional information.

Comment: @GD_Prof thanks for trying to help, the solution (posted below) seems so intuitve, I feel like I tried that solution, obviously not, because it works just fine -.-. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but it won't update the count until the threat count of 2 seconds is over

Because you are updating the label text in your `OnTimedEvent`. It fires once every two seconds.
You should put the code in your button click event.
For example:

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ClickCount++;
        clickCountLabel.Text = "Click Count: " + ClickCount;
    }
```